# Buildbot properties from changes to all build

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

I am using buildbot (system for CI) and have one problem. How can I send parameters of Change to all builders? I want to use the properties comments and who of Changes object.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm find answer: inheritance from BuildStep and use 
`self.build.allChanges()` and for set property: `self.setProperty()`